# Find text and remove with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to find and remove a specific text in a html file?

I already found a code, but I think it doesn't work if there are charkters like "/" or "()" in the HTML-File.

My HTML-Code

```
<label>Text 1 (Blue/White/Green)</label>
```

My Script

```
$("label").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/'(Blue/White/Green)'/g,""));
});
```

Comment: The regexp has quotes in it, but the text you want to replace doesn't. You also need to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to escape the slashes `/` and parentheses `()` using the antislash `\` and you should also remove the single quotes `'` and `.children()` also :

```
$("label").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\(Blue\/White\/Green\)/g,""));
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Working snippet :**

```js
$("label").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\(Blue\/White\/Green\)/g,""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Text 1 (Blue/White/Green)</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the slashes (and parens) in the regex, as well as remove the apostrophes. Secondarily, you're looking for children that don't exist, as the text is not within a child node, but the content of the label node, so removing the `.children()` filter will make it work:

```
$("label").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\(Blue\/White\/Green\)/g,""));
});
```

If you aren't interested in using a regex, you can also use the replace method with a string instead, though as written this will only replace the first instance:

```
$("label").each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('(Blue/White/Green)',""));
    });
```

Comment: And remove the apostrophes

Comment: Good point. Your jquery selector there is looking for child nodes, but there aren't any. that is the content of the label element. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `children()`. you need to iterate on the label elements. not on its children

```
$("label").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\(Blue\/White\/Green\)/g,""));
});
```

this should work

https://jsfiddle.net/L4b2m3a5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('label').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('(Blue/White/Green)', 'NOTHING')); 
});
    
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<label>Text 1 (Blue/White/Green)</label>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":contains('text-to-remove')").contents().filter(function () {
  return (this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) == 'text-to-remove');
}).remove();
```

from another poster